# Football team match result summary table

Tags: python, classes

The program is taken on the standard input a list of football team games with the result of the match and displays on the standard output a summary table of the results of all matches.

A team is awarded 3 points for a win, 0 for a loss, and 1 for a draw.

```
from collections import defaultdict

numberTeams = int(input())
dictTeams = defaultdict(list)

class Score:
    def __init__(self, number, dictTeams):
        self.number = number
        self.dictTeams = dictTeams
        self.lengthValue = 0
        self.total = 0
        self.win, self.draw, self.loss = 0, 0, 0
    def appendScore(self):
        for i in range(self.number):
            rez = input().split(';')
            self.dictTeams[rez[0]].append(3 if int(rez[1])>int(rez[3]) else 1 if int(rez[1])==int(rez[3]) else 0)
            self.dictTeams[rez[2]].append(3 if int(rez[1])<int(rez[3]) else 1 if int(rez[1])==int(rez[3]) else 0)
    def countScore(self):
        for letter, value in dictTeams.items():
            self.lengthValue = len(value)
            self.win, self.draw, self.loss = 0, 0, 0

            for i in value:
                if i==3: self.win+=1
                elif i==1: self.draw+=1
                elif i==0: self.loss+=1

            self.total = self.win*3+self.draw*1
            print(f"{letter}:{self.lengthValue} {self.win} {self.draw} {self.loss} {self.total}")

    

competition = Score(numberTeams, dictTeams)
competition.appendScore()
competition.countScore()
```

Possible input:

```
3 
Madrid;4;Spartak;5
Spartak;6;Chelsi;1
Chelsi;3;Madrid;3
```

Do I need to use classes there?

Answer (score 4):

### Layout

Place the class right after the imports.  Having the class between other
lines of code disrupts the natural flow of the code.

You should also add blank lines between the functions.

### Lint check

I ran [pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/index.html), and it identified a
few long lines of code.  You could split those up into multiple lines.

### Naming

Some of the variable names are not very meaningful, such as `lengthValue`.
Consider changing some of the names.  For example, I think `numberTeams` is
better named as `numberMatches`.  I'm not sure what `rez` stands for.

### Output description

Add header text to the printed output so you know what the the numbers
in the columns mean.  Here is the output from your input example:

```
Madrid:2 0 1 1 1
Spartak:2 2 0 0 6
Chelsi:2 0 1 1 1
```

Users have no idea what the 5 numbers after the team name means.

### Input

You should add text at the input prompt so that the user knows
what is expected for input.

You should check the input values in case the user enters
the wrong kind of value.  For example, if the user enters a word
like `dog` instead of the number of matches, the code dies badly.
The [pyinputplus](https://pypi.org/project/PyInputPlus) module
can help to check for valid input.

You should also add checking to make sure the scores are numbers,
not words.

If you have a lot of data to input, doing so at the command line is
cumbersome.  Consider storing the input as a separate file,
then reading the file instead of having the user input the data one line
at a time at the command prompt.  Entering data at the command line is
error prone; it is much easier to fix typos in a file.

### Documentation

It would be good to add some header comments at the top of the file
to describe the purpose of the code, as well as the expected input
and a description of the output.

> Do I need to use classes there?

No, you don't need to use classes, but it is fine to do so.

---

Here is re-worked code with some of the above suggestions:

```
'''
The program is taken on the standard input a list of football team games with
the result of the match and displays on the standard output a
summary table of the results of all matches.

A team is awarded 3 points for a win, 0 for a loss, and 1 for a draw.
'''

from collections import defaultdict
import pyinputplus as pyip

class Score:
    def __init__(self, number, dictTeams):
        self.number = number
        self.dictTeams = dictTeams
        self.number_matches = 0
        self.total = 0
        self.win, self.draw, self.loss = 0, 0, 0

    def appendScore(self):
        for i in range(self.number):
            rez = input(f'Match {i+1}: ').split(';')
            self.dictTeams[rez[0]].append(3 if int(rez[1])>int(rez[3])
                                            else 1 if int(rez[1])==int(rez[3]) else 0)
            self.dictTeams[rez[2]].append(3 if int(rez[1])<int(rez[3])
                                            else 1 if int(rez[1])==int(rez[3]) else 0)

    def countScore(self):
        print("Team: matches win draw loss total")
        for team, values in dictTeams.items():
            self.number_matches = len(values)
            self.win, self.draw, self.loss = 0, 0, 0

            for i in values:
                if   i==3: self.win  += 1
                elif i==1: self.draw += 1
                elif i==0: self.loss += 1

            self.total = self.win*3 + self.draw*1
            print(f"{team}: {self.number_matches} {self.win} {self.draw} {self.loss} {self.total}")

numberMatches = pyip.inputInt("Enter the number of matches: ", min=1)
dictTeams = defaultdict(list)
competition = Score(numberMatches, dictTeams)
competition.appendScore()
competition.countScore()
```

Answer (score 2):

These two lines:

```py
self.dictTeams[rez[0]].append(3 if int(rez[1])>int(rez[3]) else 1 if int(rez[1])==int(rez[3]) else 0)
self.dictTeams[rez[2]].append(3 if int(rez[1])<int(rez[3]) else 1 if int(rez[1])==int(rez[3]) else 0)
```

are not very readable.  Aside from your intention being unclear (e.g., what is `rez` and why do we care how big `rez[1]` is?), the lines are too long.  Try this:

```py
rez_1 = int(rez[1])
rez_3 = int(rez[3])
if rez_1 == rez_3:
    value_0 = 1
    value_2 = 1
elif rez_1 > rez_3:
    value_0 = 3
    value_2 = 0
else:
    value_0 = 0
    value_2 = 3

self.dictTeams[rez[0]].append(value_0)
self.dictTeams[rez[2]].append(value_2)
```

Even there, `rez_1`, `rez_3`, `value_0`, and `value_2` should probably have more descriptive names.